# specifying list as a callback data for function pointer callback using ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a c function as follows

```
void *get_queue_head(void)
char *get_element_name(void *element)
void for_each_element_in_queue(void *head, void (*callback_fn)(void *element, void *user_data), void *user_data)
```

Let 
In this example, let us say I want the callback_fn to accumulate the names of elements

The corresponding invocation would be

```
def accumlate_element_name(element, element_list):
    element_list.append(ctypes.get_element_name(element)


element_list=[] # create an empty list

def accumulate_all_element_names():
   head=ctypes.get_queue_head()
   for_each_element_in_queue(accumulate_element_name, element_list)
```

While I am able to define the function pointer for when the second-parameter for "for_each_element_in_queue" is simple object like int, I am unable to figure out how to pass an "generic-list" as parameter such that the interpretation of this can be done by the "python function"

Comment: `for_each_element_in_queue` takes three parameters: `head`, `callback_fn`, and `user_data`. I would ignore the `user_data` parameter. Just pass a `NULL` pointer for that argument (i.e. Python `None`). It's simpler to instead use a closure function or instance method for `callback_fn`. This can easily reference `element_list`.

Comment: Thanks. This is cool.  I'll give it a shot and may satisfy what I am attempting. However for the sake of completeness, are you hinting that that there is no other way?

Comment: No, a Python object can be passed as a `ctypes.py_object`, if necessary. But in this case the `user_data` parameter is really there to support languages that lack objects and closures, such as C. There's no good reason to use it in Python.